# Creating dynamic eventhandler: ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(string);

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I promise that I did search this issue before posting. :)  It may have also been answered but maybe in a different context which I could not properly understand.  The closest one that I think sort-of matches my query is this: [get-eventhandler-by-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661102/get-eventhandler-by-name).  Again, I am new to this and I am just learning as I go so please bear with me.

Anyway, my query is I have several dynamically created controls with IDs taken from a database.  Now I want to attach these controls to its related events (mostly DropDown_SelectedIndexChanged) by looping through my database and creating the events by passing a string. Hence:

```
ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(string);
```

Earlier I was hardcoding it with ifs like so:

```
if (ddl.ID == "brandCode")
{
  ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(brandCode_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

which will obviously work but it's not really dynamic.

And lol I even tried:

```
ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dr["AspId"].ToString().Trim());
```

which is obviously wrong because it is passing a string instead of an object.

Disclaimer.  This question is related to my earlier post [Dynamically created cascading dropdown lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631621/dynamically-created-cascading-dropdown-lists)